# Remove Buttons from Gtk.Dialog Action Area in GTK3

Tags: python, gtk3

I'm trying to remove the added Buttons (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDialog.html#gtk-dialog-add-button) from the Action-Area of the Gtk.Dialog Widget. Is there a opportunity without creating a new Dialog?

Answer (score 0):

What may work is to save a reference to the button that you will later want to remove:

```
button = dialog.add_button('OK', 3)
# ... later ...
button.get_parent().remove(button)
```

Previously you could use `dialog.get_action_area()` and then remove all its children, but direct access to the action area is discouraged these days.